# How does recursion work here?

Tags: java, recursion

Recursion is a new practice for me and I am trying to get better at it and understand how the methods return. I have the following program but am unfailiar with how to use the `this` keyword. Can you please review the code and walk me through the program showing the values held by the variables as the methods execute?

I have tried numerous things to determine how the value answer in the compute method holds 14 after execution can anyone walk me through the first few recursive calls so I can try and figure out the rest?

```
public class Recurs1 {
    public static void main (String [] arg) {
        Recurs1 r = new Recurs1();
        r.compute();

    }
    public void compute() {
        int [] stuff = {1, 2, 3, 4};
        int answer = this.go(stuff, 0);
        System.out.println("The answer is " + answer);

    }
    private int go(int[] numbers, int spot) {
        if (numbers.length == spot) return spot;
        int value = this.go(numbers, spot + 1 ); 
        return value + numbers[spot];
    }

}
```

Comment: Why don't you give it a try first and let us know how you do?  In particular, if you struggle or don't understand the results you get you can ask a specific question.

Comment: Sounds like a perfect time to start learning how to use a debugger. Otherwise this just smells like homework.

Comment: Also, what is your confusion with using `this` in this context?  You can omit the keyword here and it will be functionally and semantically equivalent.

Comment: The return value of `go(stuff, 0);` is 14. Should it be 10?

Comment: I always encourage people to "play computer" with some paper and a pencil, particularly when struggling through recursion. You can even use a small array, like with two or three elements. Just write down every single step the program is taking, indent what you write to show recursion depth, etc. It pays off in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so a few things I notice here:

The purpose of go() seems to be calculating the sum of the numbers in the array.  If this is the case, your method should look like this:

```
private int go(int[] numbers, int spot) {
        if (numbers.length - 1 == spot) return numbers[spot];
        int value = this.go(numbers, spot + 1 ); 
        return value + numbers[spot];
    }
```

This is because numbers.length in this case will return 4, but the last element in this array is at index 3 (arrays are 0-indexed).

This way, when the function is called with the second parameter set to 3, it will return the value of the last element in the array and then the code will "bubble up" (as I like to call it) and calculate the sum of the elements by subsequently returning the current summed value + the value of the current call.

As for your problem with the `this` keyword, it's actually very simple.  `this` always refers to the current class instance your code is in.  In this case, you create a `Recurs1` instance called `r` in your main function so whenever you call a method on that particular object, the `this` keyword used in those methods will refer to `r`.  If you created multiple `Recurs1` objects (each with potential different internal states) in your program, their respective `this` references would always point to themselves allowing you to access their member variables and methods.

Hope that helps and good luck, recursion is usually what most people have trouble getting their heads around at first but once you get used to it it's pretty cool!

Answer (score 0):

OK so this is not an answer to your question per se, more like a lesson in recursion.

Keep in mind I have never tried to to do this with a java class.

Recursion means a function that calls itself repeatedly until a answer has been reached, or your function detects you are running out of **stack** space.

You first step into the function determines if you will call yourself.

When you call yourself you will push a new copy of the data onto the stack and begin executing.  I *think* in the case of java you will allocate a new object into the *heap* ( don't quote me on this ) and each invocation will have a new set of variables that get populated with new values.

As you recurse deeper and deeper you simply allocate new copies of the object until you find the answer or run out of memory.

If you find the answer you then return the result to the previous level in the stack of objects eg:

```
int foo(int i ){
  if(some condition){ 
   return foo(i);
  } else
   return i  
}
```

as You can see if the condition tests true the foo() keeps getting called.  Now at each call, the variables of foo() are saved for as many levels deep as you go.  If the condition tests false then each instance of foo() returns to the previous until you are at the original invocation of foo() which then returns to the caller of foo().

Clear as Mud?